# Showing that the roots of an equation are real and distinct.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help showing that the roots of the equation $px^2 - 3x - p = 0$ are real and distinct for all real values of $p$.

After some help from the previous answers, I am now stuck on $4p^2 + 9 > 0$.

I have tried to solve this for $\gt30$ minutes, but I cannot understand how to solve it.
What do I need to do after this?

Comment: What is the discriminant?

Comment: (member for today)It is strongly discouraging for new users to receive 4 downvotes with no explanation as to why. Especially considering he has stated he has no idea how to start it. The four downvotes are in my opinion unfair.

Comment: @user151558 I'd argue that the downvotes were directed at the title; it was amusingly bad.

Comment: @EulCan I will admit that I chuckled at the original title.

Comment: i don't know. i'm new really.

Comment: @user171257: Cheer up! Don't get discouraged. I myself received unknown downvotes from time to time. If you stick to write your question as if you were writing a paper, then you know for sure that downvotes are not necessarily all because of you. In our time, fewer and fewer are patient persons.

Comment: @Brian Let us be specific here: downvoting a title+question that reads "What's your math question? Be specific. show that roots of the equation px^2 - 3x - p = 0 are real and distinct for all real values of p." does not strike me as a display of *impatience*. Comforting new users is alright, to mislead them about the ways of the site is not.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  A quadratic has $2$ real roots if & only if $$b^2-4ac>0$$

In your case, $$a=p,\quad b=-3,\quad c=-p$$

Try substituting these values in.

After substituting, note that for all real $p,\quad p^2\geq0$. So clearly $p^2+9>0$ and $4p^2+9>0$.

Since the condition is satisfied, what you're looking for must be true. I think you may have  been over-thinking this somewhat.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: i have done it.. but start from 9 + 4p^2 > 0 i don't know what goes after that..

Comment: the down vote is not mine.. really..

Comment: @user171257 I've added a sentence to clarify. Fortunately, the downvote's gone. Does my answer make sense?

Comment: ya.. thankyou :)

Comment: @user171257 One last sidenote: for $p=0$, the equation is linear and the quadratic formula would be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Using the quadratic equation, where $a=p=-c,b=-3$

We obtain from $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \Rightarrow \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{(-3)^2 + 4p^2}}{2p}$

Comment: @RainiervanEs It does in this case though, unless I am missing something.

$a=p$,$c=-p$, multiply by minus one, $-c=p$, and $a=p$ hence $a=p=-c$